# How to select specific country from dropdown list in EF when page loads in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have used EF to populate data from database in dropdown list for country. I have more than 100 countries in the dropdown list.

But I want to select one specific country `New Zealand` when page loads.

Can you advise me how to do this?

```
 private static List<SelectListItem> GetCountries()
        {
            AayuDBEntities db = new AayuDBEntities();
            List<SelectListItem> CountriesList = (from p in db.Countries.AsEnumerable()
                                               select new SelectListItem
                                               {
                                                   Text = p.Name,
                                                   Value = p.Country_Id.ToString()
                                               }).ToList();



            return CountriesList;
        }
```

.cshtml code

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.Country, Model.Countries, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control"})
```

Comment: Hi.

What have you tried so far ?
Please ["read this"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  before posting a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

follow this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
m => m.CountryId, // Specifies where to store selected country Id
                  // It needs to be null for the default selection to work!

new SelectList(Model.Countries, // IEnumerable<Country>, contains all countries loaded from a database
               "Id",   // Use Country.Id as a data source for the values of dropdown items
               "Name", // Use Country.Name as a data source for the text of dropdown items
               13 // Specifies Australia (which has ID of 13) as the element selected by default
               ),
```

Comment: it says, there are also comments, what guide do you need?

Comment: I am using different way to populate the data in dropdown and you have used different way.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SlectedValue, Model.CountryList, "Please select", new { id = "ddlCity" })
```

Do this way ,May be this helps. :)

Comment: I do not want to use `Please select`. I want to select country New Zealand when the page loads.

Comment: OK@user11642353